# How to find an upper bound for this question?

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are playing a dice game in which a pair of dice is rolled repeatedly.
Asami wins if a 6 is rolled before any number greater than or equal to 9, and $B$ wins if any number greater than or equal to 9 is rolled first. We will find the probability that $A$ wins the game.

Now, suppose that in a run of this game, the dice are rolled ten
times with neither a 6 nor any number greater than or equal to 9 appearing.
Given this, let $X$ be the sum of these ten rolls. We would now like to find an upper bound for the following probability $\mathbb{P}[|X − 1220
21 | \geq 10]$.

I understand that to find an upper-bound , we have to use Chebyshev's Inequality , I just dont understand how its supposed to fit in this, what is the SD in this? the variance? [Chebyshevs inequality that i know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atZkc.jpg)

Comment: First, you must calculate the variance as follows: $Var(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-[\mathbb{E}(X)]^2$ where $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is the expected value of the random variable $X$ and is given by $\sum_{k=10}^{60} k\mathbb{P}(X=k)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ is given by $\sum_{k=10}^{60} k^2\mathbb{P}(X=k)$